# Как в классе узнать имя атрибута класса который вызвал атрибут в этом же классе

Tags: python-3.x

Например :

```
class A:

def atr_one(self):
    self.atr_two() 

def atr_two(self):
    print('atr_two')  # Как узнать кто его вызывает
```

Comment: Или таким способом я не узнаю кто его вызывал, так как искомый объект находится внутри другого?

Answer (score 1):

```
class A:

    def atr_one(self):
        self.atr_two("def atr_one")

    def atr_two(self, text="def atr_two"):
        print(text)  # Как узнать кто его вызывает

a = A()

a.atr_one()
def atr_one

a.atr_two()
def atr_two
```

Comment: Просто для наглядности пойдет! Но совсем не, то! Необходимо узнать что это за объект.А так получается хитрость  в виде переменной.

Comment: хотя решит мою проблему, но хотелось бы все-таки узнать имя объектов.

Answer (score 1):

```
import inspect

def f1(): f2()

def f2():
    print 'caller name:', inspect.stack()[1][3]

f1()
```

источник: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654113/how-to-get-the-callers-method-name-in-the-called-method